# How does Calendar.getInstance() know the current year?

Tags: java, calendar

How does `Calendar.getInstance()` method get you the current year? It doesn't read it from your computer obviously neither from the internet. This may sound like a newbie question but how does this method work?

Comment: If it wasn't reading it from your computer, nor from an external source, the it would either have to be guessing or psychic!

Comment: LOL!! It confused me since I changed the year on my PC and I still got 2010!!!

Comment: You might need to restart Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it does read it from your computer. Internally, it calls `GregorianCalendar`'s constructor, which calls `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is a native method.

Depending on your locale, it might also create a `JapaneseImperialCalendar` or a `BuddhistCalendar`, which also both call `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar.getInstance()
```

is just a shortcut for

```
new GregorianCalendar()
```

which initializes itself using:

```
setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

So the trick is

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

which indeed **does** read it from your computer.

Comment: It isn't a shortcut. It returns the suitable instance for the current locale. In locales using a Gregorian calendar, a `GregorianCalendar` will be returned by the abstract factory method.

Comment: You are right. I was looking here (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html, line 984) which seems to differ from the JDK.